# Image position compensation in EMGU CV

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, emgucv

I have hit a roadblock with this issue that I have in my project.
i have an image with three printed objects and i want to check if the objects moves up or down during printing. If it does above/beyond the threshold limit it needs to be rejected.

E.G:
[image: CLick here for image]

The above image shows a good sample, i select an ROI around all the 3 objects to reduce inspection time. But the problem is, the product shifts a bit during printing, although the print is good, the image apprears shifted within my ROI and the coordinates changes which leads them to get rejected.

EG:

[image: CLick here for image]

How do I keep the image centered(ROI'd image) with reference to the center object (center object never shifts during printing).

i'm using template matching to find the objects as follows :

```
            Image<Bgr, Byte> templateImage = img_tofind;
            Image<Bgr, Byte> sourceImage = ROI_Image;

            using (Image<Gray, float> imgMatch = 
             sourceImage.MatchTemplate(templateImage, 
              Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED))
            {

                Point[] MAX_Loc, Min_Loc;
                double[] min, max;
                imgMatch.MinMax(out min, out max, out Min_Loc, out 
                 MAX_Loc);

                using (Image<Gray, double> RG_Image = 
                imgMatch.Convert<Gray, double>().Copy())
                {
                  if (max[0] > 0.60)
                    {
                        Rectangle match = new Rectangle(MAX_Loc[0], 
                        templateImage.Size);
                        sourceImage.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Red), 1);

                        int hw = match.Width;
                        int hh = match.Height;
                        int htlx = match.X;
                        int htly = match.Y;

                        hres1 = htlx + hw / 2; Object COG X
                        hres2 = htly + hh / 2;  Object COG Y

                    }

                }
                ibresult.Image = sourceImage;
            }
```

I want the ROI image to always be centered with reference to the center object.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for your issue. We need some code to help you in your case.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question, im using template macthing to locate object within the ROI, and find the objects centroid and then measure its movement. But when the product shifts, the image with the roi shifts which makes the centroid of the object shift resulting in a false rejection.

Comment: find distance between three circles using their centroids, and check if the distance exceeds or below some theshold then reject

Comment: I already tried did that, but the customer wants to check the X and Y positions of the objects individually.